# Q-ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, installation, pip

Its showing the below error.

> pip install selenium

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/selenium/
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/selenium/
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/selenium/
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/selenium/
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/selenium/
> **ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for selenium**

Could anyone please help in resolving this issue.

Selenium was working fine in my system but some connection error were coming, So I have uninstalled it. Now, After restarting the system I am unable to install Selenium back neither in system nor in Virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

### Possible Solutions

Hi, it seems like either your network connection to PyPI is being blocked by a firewall, or your `pip` needs to be updated.

#### Updating `pip`

You can try installing `selenium` after you update `pip`

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

#### Removing Firewall

Another issue is that your firewall could be blocking connecting to PyPI, trust me I have seem my fair share of this issue. You can give it go after whitelisting the following domains and then it should do the trick.

- pypi.python.org
- pypi.org
- pythonhosted.org
- files.pythonhosted.org

To test this theory out you can connect to a VPN and give it a go, if that fixes it then go ahead and whitelist the above domains for seamless installs.

I hope this helps!

Comment: first solution will not work, as connecting to pypi is not possible

Comment: @FlyingTeller yeah agreed but the second one should do the trick.